# mysql tunnel restrict server login

Tags: mysql, login, ssh-tunnel

We currently only allow external mysql access by using ssh tunnels (with a variety of read only/write/admin users) with each end-user having a different user login on the server. Is it possible to stop them from ssh-ing into the server but still enable them to tunnel to mysql?

This is on ubuntu 14.10 server using the default `dash`

Answer (score 1):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/disable-user-shell-for-security-reasons

I think you want this

this would disable shell for user, but the connectivity will remain

> usermod -s /sbin/nologin myuser

Comment: This does indeed stop the user being able to ssh in, but unfortunately this disabled the user being able to login to MySQL over ssh tunnel

Comment: Did you try /bin/false shell too ? What command do you exactly use to ssh ? It should open port, but shell will remain closed

Comment: I tried it with port 22 and it works, you must be doing something wrong; command i used: ssh -N -L 1234:host:22 -l public host; with shell /bin/false. perhaps you dont have /sbin/nologin binary

Comment: If your users use a rsa key for autentication, you can use the no-pty option in the authorized_keys file. This will prevent your users to open a terminal. Warning, they will be still able to launch remote commands through ssh.